# Chain fetch Requests in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a site that fetches Reddit content and displays it to the user. My main problem is my `LCP` time with Google is taking a hit due to the API returning such a large data set and causing a delay.

I'm wondering if I can fetch the first 10x Posts, then chain another `fetch` call to append the rest of the data?

Current Call:

```
  async fetch() {
        // Fetch this pages URL from the API. Use the options if there are any to use.
        await this.$axios.get(this.baseUrl + this.builtUrl + '/' + this.sortOption + '.json?raw_json=1&limit=100')
        .then((response) => {
            // Build Reddit Array
            this.posts = response.data.data.children
            // Add the next page Variable.
            this.nextPage = response.data.data.after
            // Set the Page Variable.
            this.page = response.data.data.after
        })
  },
```

As you can see, it's getting 100x Posts. Is it possible to change this to 10 then append the other 90 in a chained fetch call? Tried a few methods, but they seem overly complex?

Comment: Depends of the API. Did you checked if there is something like that? Otherwise, you can also go full static and not have to fetch the content at all if using `ssr: true` + `target: 'static'`.

Comment: Thanks @kissu - how would changing to full static effect the dynamic data from the API? Would I have to purge it with a deploy?

Comment: My SSR is set to `true` at the moment.

Comment: No need to purge it, you call the API, generate the content at a given time. Then, your build will be using that as static data and will not reach back for the API (once deployed). You could make an automatic generation every day or so if needed. Give a read to some articles like this one: https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/going-full-static/